# Deleting Instances in C++ Factory

Tags: c++, inheritance, factory-pattern, delete-operator

I came across this C++ factory pattern, and I like how the ownership lies with the consumer:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void Create(MyClass **instance, int some_param);
    void Destroy(MyClass *instance);

    void SomeAction() = 0;
}

// Use it

MyClass *instance;

MyClass::Create(&instance, 5);
instance->SomeAction();
MyClass::Destroy(instance);
```

But how do you implement `Destroy`? I imagine `Create` will look something like:

```
void MyClass::Create(MyClass **instance, int some_param) {
    // Subtype in some way derived from some_param
    if (some_param == 1) {
        *instance = (MyClass *) new MyClassSubClass();
    }
    // if some_param == 2, use MyDifferentSubClass() etc...
}
```

I've tried something like the following for `Destroy`, but can't get it to work:

```
void MyClass::Destroy(MyClass *instance) {
    delete instance;
}
```

Maybe `delete` needs to know the particular subclass (to know its allocation size)? But this doesn't seem to work either:

```
void MyClass::Destroy(MyClass *instance) {
    if (some_param == 1) {
        delete (MyClassSubClass *)instance
    }
}
```

Any input or alternative approaches very welcome.

Comment: What you mean by "but can't get it to work:"? it should work just fine provided `MyClass` destructor is virtual.

Comment: `delete` would work fine provided `MyClass` has a virtual destructor and `instance` points to an object of a type `MyClass` or derived.

Comment: FWIW, in modern C++ (calling it "modern" is a bit of stretch here, because I actually mean "C++ from this millenium"), you would make ownership lie with the client by returning an owning handle.

Comment: Ok, so would returning a `unique_ptr` and not providing a `Destroy`er be a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete(instance);` should work. You forgot to add a virtual destructor in MyClass:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    virtual ~MyClass();

    void Create(MyClass **instance, int some_param);
    void Destroy(MyClass *instance);

    void SomeAction() = 0;
}
```

Comment: if your class requires the use of `Destroy` you should make the destructor a private member to prevent accidental use of it outside of the class...

Answer (score 1):

All `MyClass` needs is a virtual destructor, and the compiler/run time will do the rest.